# How to find the complex number based on its argument?

Tags: complex-numbers

Suppose I've the following:

$$\arg(2+i5-z) = 0.9$$

How can I find $z$? Wolfram says it's $-1.96$, but I didn't understand how to get this value.

EDIT: I wrote originally that the answer was 2, but it's in fact 0.90.

Comment: All the numbers on a ray from the origin have the save argument, so there isn't a unique value of $z$ that satisfies the equation.

Comment: *Wolfram says it's −1.96* Where is the corresponding link?

Comment: Actually I copied wrong, it was supposed to be arg(2+i5-z) = 0.9. But here it's: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=arg%282%2Bi5+-+z%29+%3D+0.9

Comment: Your question should be : How to find a Real number ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**hint**

Put
$$z=a+ib$$

then

$$Z=2+5i-z=(2-a)+i(5-b)$$

with

$$\frac{5-b}{2-a}=\;\tan(0.9)$$

There are a lot of solutions.

If you look for real solution, with $ b=0$, you will get
$$\frac{5}{2-a}=\tan(0.9)=1.26$$
So
$$a=z=-1.96$$

Comment: Not my downvote but $\arg(z)=\arctan\frac yx$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I just edited it.